# toggleClass not working

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'm having problem with 'toggleClass'. What this script do is it adds a new set of field depending on the radio buttons value. Inside the field is a new div that is hidden by default and will be displayed only if the 'a' is triggered by a click event. At first it works but once I click on another radio button or at the same radio button the 'toggleClass' dont work anymore.

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.duplicatorRadio').click(function() {
          var this_index_limit = parseInt($(this).val());
          for(var i = 0; i < this_index_limit; i++) {
             if(!$('#text_box_' + i).length) {
                var headerValue = parseInt(i) + 1;
                $(
                  '<fieldset id="text_box_' + i + '"> <h3>Property ' + headerValue +' Information</h3> <a class="borrowerToggler" href="#">Show Co-Borrower</a> <div class="borrower hide"> <h5>Co-Borrower Information</h5></div></fieldset>'
                  ).appendTo($(this).parent());
             }
             else if($('#text_box_' + i).css('display') == 'none') {
                $('#text_box_' + i).show();
             }
          }

          $('fieldset').each(function() {
             var split_id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
             if(!split_id.length) return;
             var index = parseInt(split_id[2]);
             if(index >= this_index_limit) {
                 $(this).hide();
             }
          });

          $("a.borrowerToggler").click(function(){
            $(this).next("div").toggleClass("hide");
          });

      });

  });
```

Comment: Paste your HTML code also. If possible post your entire code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: can you remove hide as argument to toggleclass and give a try ...

Comment: i think , $(this) is creating some issue next time, can you alert $(this) both the times and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to bind click event. [`This demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/HMKDf/) might hlp you.

Comment: Live has been deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. "on" method is the recommended method to use now.